# What "building" is the man on the phone referring to?

Tags: tenet

In India, Protagonist walks out of a shop while talking on the phone:

> Man on phone: I was told you left the **building**.
>
> Protagonist: Even the dead need allies.
>
> Man on phone: Specifically?
>
> Protagonist: I need an assist in Mumbai. I need to get to Sanjay Singh.

What "building" is the man on the phone referring to?

Comment: its a figure of speech "You left this world" or "you were dead"...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_has_left_the_building

Comment: I fear you may be under the impression that if you clarify enough details about Tenet, it'll make sense 

Comment: @Shreedhar Make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "*has left the building*" is used informally to emphasize that someone has gone and **will not return**, i.e., **dead**.

In the movie, the Protagonist is presumed dead after the events that followed the opening clash at the Opéra. That's the reason why the man on the phone says so.

To support this, listen to how the Protagonist responds:

> Even the *dead* need allies.

indicating that *left the building* meant *dead/deceased*.